# Графический интерфейс + методы

Tags: java

Имеется графический интерфейс, который в будущем будет активно использовать много различных методов (работа с сетью, работа с файлами и др.). Как правильно это организовать? Есть мысль запихнуть все методы в один класс, сделать статическими и вызывать их из класса граф. интерфейса. Но правильно ли это?

Comment: Лучше реализовать разный функционал в разных классах, не валить все в одну кучу

Comment: @Augoustis, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ни в коем случае нельзя вызывать из GUI потока долго работающие методы (например, работающие с сетью). Ожидая их завершения, графический интерфейс намертво подвиснет, что отрицательно скажется на впечатлении пользователя о вашей программе. Лучшим решением будет запуск продолжительных операций в отдельных потоках, которые по завершении уведомят GUI поток и отдадут ему результаты, которые он сможет отобразить. Хорошим решением будет использование шаблона проектирования "[Заместитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)".